# "get in touch with <email>" or "get in touch at <email>"

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs

> if you have any support question, please get in touch at support@mycompany.com

To me, the phrase 'get in touch with' seems to be more common.

I would like to know if there is any substantial difference between 'at' and 'with' in term of meaning. Which one is preferred in this example? (i.e. used in combination with an email instead of a person or place)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your usage there is practically no difference, this is because the user is asked to make contact using an email address and this address represents both the location and a team of "support" people.  You could have easily said

> Please get in touch ***with*** support ***at*** support@mycompany.com
>   *Please get in touch with someone in support by email at support@mycompany.com*